# Django ORM: SELECT on field attributes

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that contains a FileField. I want to search for a specific filename. How do I do it? I was trying:

```
MyModel.objects.get(document__name=FOO)
```

I got a Join on field 'document' is not permitted.

Thanks!

Comment: Might help to share your models.

Comment: document is a standard FileField and name is a standard attribute of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on document, and it'll filter by the string that is the path on disk to the file.

Answer (score 2):

The attributes of a `FileField` are not stored in the database, and cannot be used in a query.   For example, the name is simply the `upload_to` string plus the filename.  If you want to store extra data about the file you have to put that data into other fields on the database, as the [example documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#using-files-in-models) shows with a Car having a name of "57 Chevy".

Also, typically the double underscore in Django's ORM denotes following a database relationship, either a `ForeignKey` or a `ManyToMany`.  So in the example ORM call you provided, I would assume that `MyModel` had a field `document` that was either a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToMany` to another model, and that other model has a field called `name`.  Which doesn't sound like is the case.

Hope that helps some.

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
MyModel.objects.get(document__icontains='FOO')
```